# What does "trigger-happy on broken windows" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, expressions, colloquialisms

What does this expression mean:

- to be ["trigger-happy on broken windows"](https://english.stackexchange.com/election#post-12718)

Comment: I'm comment-happy on E.SE.

Comment: See what I mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/):

- **trigger-happy**: *someone who is trigger-happy is much too willing to use weapons, especially guns*

> a trigger-happy cop

Broken windows refers to those questions he mentioned in the paragraph above which are extremely poor, blatantly off-topic questions.

So I think, he means using more of his power of being a moderator to delete those kind of questions.

Answer (score 8):

The "broken windows" part refers, at a bit of a distance, to the ["broken windows"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) criminological theory, which is basically that allowing the effects of bad behavior to visibly persist encourages bad behavior.  "Trigger-happiness" is the condition of being ready to "pull the trigger" on some capability at minimal provocation.  The writer is saying that he will become more aggressive about policing visible effects of blatant misbehavior (in counterpoint to his earlier assertion, that he will become less aggressive about policing arguably acceptable behavior).

Comment: Hmmm... arguably an example of chiasmus?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds to me like the expression "to flog a dead horse", meaning doing something that has no purpose: the horse is already dead, so why flog him.
Similarly, if the windows are already broken, then what's the point in shooting them?